# Apply default filter if query returns 0 rows - Oracle Plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, null, nvl

Im using Oracle PLSQL. Im trying to make a join beetween two tables and make a filter from one parameter that can be 'W' (Woman) or 'M' (Man).

I have this table with a list of Jobs:

[image: Jobs Table]

And this other one with every job translated to English or Spanish for each gender:

[image: Jobs Language]

I want to get the job translated to both languages for the gender specified in the parameter. If there is no translation for Woman, then get translation for Man.

I tried to do this with NVL but it's not working:

```
select j.*, l.long_name, l.language, l.gender 
from job j
join job_lang l
on j.id = l.id_job
where j.short_name = 'Firefighter'
and nvl(l.gender, 'M') = 'M'; -- parameter
```

It works perfect when the parameter is 'M' but returns nothing when is 'W' because there is no translation for Woman.

[image]

I'm not sure if I can do this with a case, I tried but I couldn't find anything. Could you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Jobs per gender?  Just two days after RBG died?  Very strange question.

Comment: In the table in your question, `Profesor` has gender `W` and `Profesora` also has gender `W`. Is there a mistake in the table, or did I make a mistake reading it?

Comment: I see Oracle SQL, not PL/SQL which is the programming language.

Comment: What's your oracle version?

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov oracle 18c

Comment: @Abra It's a mistake, 'Profesor' should bev M, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would aggregate it before join:

```
select j.*, l.language, l.long_name_M, l.long_name_W
from job j
join (
      select 
         jl.id_job,jl.language
        ,max(decode(jl.gender,'M',long_name) long_name_M
        ,max(long_name)keep(dense_rank first order by decode(jl.gender,'W',1,'M',2)) long_name_W
      from job_lang jl
      group by jl.id_job,jl.language
      ) l
      on j.id = l.id_job
where j.short_name = 'Firefighter';
```

PS. Oracle can push predicates into group-by inline view

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `fetch` clause with window functions for prioritization:

```
    select j.*, l.long_name, l.language, l.gender, 
    from job j
    join job_lang l on j.id = l.id_job
    where j.short_name = 'Firefighter'
    order by row_number() over(
        partition by j.id, l.language
        order by case when l.gender = 'M' then 0 else 1 end
    )                                  ^----- parameter
    fetch first row with ties
```